# How to connect PHP file to HTML file without Ajax

Tags: php, html

If I am creating a web page with a HTML form where the information inputted by the user needs to be processed by PHP and then the results returned as a HTML form, how do I go about this?

I have a index.html file with the form on .. how do I get the information onto the php and then back again to show the results?

Comment: Could you let us know the reason you don't want to use Ajax for this (assuming you don't want a page reload when submitting the form?). Putting restrictions on solutions without letting us know the reasoning, makes it way harder for us to come up with good alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for you to send data to an external php file e.g: `external_file.php` is through ajax or a submitted form, which in this case will take you to the php file with the data:

```
<form action="external_file.php" method="get">
```

Or you could use this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="get">
```

But by doing this you will have to change your `index.html` file to `index.php`, and the code to handle the requests which is in `external_file.php` will have to be put in this `index.php` file.
You will still be in the same page but the page will be loaded again with the new data, and you could use `method="post"` so as not to tamper with the URL and also when submitting secure data.

Other than those methods, you will have to use `AJAX` to send and receive data from `external_file.php` without leaving the page.